# Iterate through list and list of map

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got list of strings named list and list of map named type

list ['value1', 'value2']

type [{data: 'value1', isSelected: false},{data: 'value5', isSelected: false}]

I want to update isSelected value in 'type' list if value in list is equal to type.data value

I managed to do it this way

```
if (type != null) {
  for (var l in list) {
    for (var t in type) {
      if (l.data == t) {
        l.isSelected = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a more decent way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to know if the value of data is contained in the list array, you only need 1 loop:

```
var list = ['value1', 'value2'];
var type = [{data: 'value3', isSelected: false}, {data: 'value4', isSelected:false}]

for (t in type) {
  if (list.contains(t.data)) { // changed from indexOf as recommended in comments
    t.isSelected = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: As an alternative to indexOf() contains is a little more readable. `if (list.contains(t.data))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for` with `contains` and when data is found no need to continue further. Hence, break the loop.

```
var list = ['value1', 'value2'];
var type = [{data: 'value3', isSelected: false}, {data: 'value4', isSelected:false}]
```

**Edit**

```
for (object in type) {
  if (list.contains(object['data'])) { // changed from indexOf as recommended in comments
    object['isSelected'] = true;
    break:
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually I just read about this. `forEach` loops don't `break` they run the entire loop no matter what. You can see that `break` is running inside a callback function not in a loop. So your solution works but it doesn't have the performance benefit you indicate. If you use a `for` loop you can use `break` and gain performance by not unnecessarily completing the loop.

Comment: @SydneyY yes you're right `foreach` will not break in dart it's better to use `for loop` . Cheers :)